# Find all days of a week/month/year and add to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

I have an NSMutableArray, and i want to be able to pull out only the rows that are in a cetain time frame such as each week or month or year. I can get a date thats a week back so i would have the current date and the date a week back, but i need to be able to grab all those days then add them to an array so i can search through them.

This is how i am grabbing the day and the day a week back.

```
-(void)getCalDays {
cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)fromDate:date];
today = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];


   NSLog(@"today is %@", today);
    [self getWeek];
}

-(void)getWeek {
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setDay:-6];
    weekDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
    NSLog(@"Week of %@ THRU %@", today, weekDate);
}
```

So how can i find all the days in between the two dates and load them into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on your way.  The key is to advance the component's day in a loop and extract a date from them.

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDate *startDate = // your input start date
NSDate *endDate = // your input end date

NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)fromDate:startDate];
NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];

while (![date isEqualToDate:endDate]) {
    [result addObject:date];
    [comps setDay:(comps.day + 1)];
    date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

Note that this will result in a collection of dates *inclusive* of the first date, *exclusive* of the last date.  You can probably work out on your own how to change the edge conditions.